# Why is the OneNote API lagging by roughly 3 days on my account?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

**In short, getting page information for my notes through the OneNote API has data that lags by about 3 days. Why is this the case (I assume only for me) and how can this be fixed?**

I'm working on a personal R program to read my OneNote Notes. Got it up and running about a week ago. Authentication works fine and I can use GET requests to get information from the OneNote API. However, the information that is returned about my OneNote pages (using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages`) is about 3 days old. New notes from the past 3 days and changes made in the last 3 days are not reflected in this data. It is not frozen in time, i.e. checking tomorrow will give me information that is 3 days behind tomorrow. This is not solely an issue with my application, as the same behavior/results are produced through the Microsoft Graph Explorer. Does anyone have insight on how to fix this?

Comment: Just to follow-up: this is the ~7th straight day of this behavior. Using Graph Explorer today only pulls up notes and changes from 12/29/19, so it looks like the delay is even greater. I would really appreciate being able to use this API to get more up to date information about my notes. Again, any input on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this behavior is still true as of Jan. 30. Calls to get the pages of a section, or pages in general return indexes of very stale information. To test, delete or create a bunch of pages in your OneNote account, then call in the API Explorer:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages

You will be given information about deleted pages, and no new information for at least *days* after these changes have been made. If you follow the returned 'contentUrl' properties for deleted pages, the content does not exist.

It seems other endpoints in the OneNote API are not subject to this same problem. Adding/removing/updating sections, for example, results in immediate changes to the results from the API.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that. Just to clarify, are you using your personal account or work account for auth?

Comment: Thanks for checking in - sorry for the delay. The problem is still going (my last updated note from the API is from January 3rd). I am signed in under a personal account (@hotmail.com).

Comment: Also, I conducted a [little experiment to see the extent of this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637838/onenote-api-pages-endpoint-not-working-properly). In short, this does not appear to be restricted to my account or the program that I'm developing.