# Onenote API (once again) not returning new pages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

As of yesterday, it appears that the Onenote /pages endpoint is not working properly for my account. The data returned for the first two pages is recent, however all other pages and their respective HTML content links are last updated as of Feb 28th 2020. Additionally, some of the pages showing up as "last edited" on Feb 28th 2020 are pages that I know for a fact have not been edited for months (place holders, old projects, etc.)

I have described a similar problem before: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637838/onenote-api-pages-endpoint-not-working-properly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546904/why-is-the-onenote-api-lagging-by-roughly-3-days-on-my-account). Such a problem was also described by [another recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836607/onenote-api-is-not-returning-new-pages-even-via-ms-graph-explorer). Upon resolution of those issues, Manjusha stated that it was because of a "bad machine cluster causing jobs to get stuck" and therefore delaying updates. While this suffices to explain the delay, the inaccurate edit dates on page does not seem to be accounted for.

Any updates on the issue or insight into what is happening would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE Mar. 5th 2020**: Using the graph explorer, I can see that the pages endpoint is returning the same out-date response again and again. Basically, it is frozen in that state from what I can see.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say this, especially at such a stressful time. However, the reliability of the pages endpoint has been up in the air for months. Working sometimes, not working at others. Personally, this has forced me to rebuild my personal programs so they do not rely on OneNote and reconsider using OneNote in professional settings where new pages are being made regularly. The sum total of this has been to cease development and usage of the OneNote API. Just a bit of feedback. I know your team works hard and these issues are complex - I hope this clears up for you soon.

Answer (score 1):

Can you send the request-id header from the response and your request timestamp? Thanks!

Comment: request-id: 023a3919-fab8-4d70-ae65-6d2230b76aa8
Sent the request just now, at 7:45AM EST on March 4, 2020 via Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Quick backstory on the issue, the last page is dated as edited on Mar 2nd and the bulk of the pages are dated as edited Feb 28th. It has been this way for a few days. I use Onenote pretty much everyday (multiple notes made, multiple notes edited) and have custom programs that analyze my notes using the API.

Comment: At this point, it looks like the page endpoint is just frozen - returning the exact same thing day after day.

Comment: Thank you so much Keshov! It's great to know that you use OneNote just as much as I do :)  What I was looking for, was a request-id for a newly created page request. Do you happen to have the page Id or can you share the request-id from the Create-page request: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/section-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hi Manjusha - I just used graph explorer to post the HTML from the sample page at the link. It showed up in the correct section in my notebook i.e. I can view it using OneNote. request-id: 3d4e1c65-fd14-4070-b594-2affc8af5881, page id (from JSON response) "id": "0-2973e7176f924bd1a29b1ddd01d47fd7!27-CA24ECD9622C684C!2433". When I send a GET request for the pages in the section it was posted to, I do not get any new information. The new page not there and same order of old info that has been this way for a ~week. thanks for your attention to this.

Comment: Another follow-up. It seems that recently edited page from another notebook is being accurately returned by the pages endpoint. However, my Main Notebook (that stores 99% of my frequently used notes), is still not updating.

Comment: Thanks for the update...we are still investigating...will reply back once we have an update.

Comment: Hello Keshov, are you able to see your recently updated pages? We made a fix recently and wanted to check with you. Thanks!